# Loading spinner not showing

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase in a react native app along with the spinner from `'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'`.
Im trying to show the spinner while the user is authenticating to firebase but the spinner isn't showing up. This is the function that handles an user trying to auth:

```
const [spinnerState, setSpinnerState] = useState(false)
...
const handleAuthenticationAttempt = () => {
            if (emailStatus == false || passwordStatus == false) {
                  Alert.alert(
                        "ERROR",
                        "Something went wrong... Please make sure you have inserted all data correctly.",
                        [{
                              text: "OK",
                              style: "ok",
                        }])
            } else {
                  const auth = getAuth(app);
                  setSpinnerState(true)
                  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                        .then(() => {
                              setSpinnerState(false)
                              console.log("success")
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                              Alert.alert(
                                    "ERROR",
                                    "Something went wrong... Please check the email and password you entered is correct: " + error.code,
                                    [{
                                          text: "OK",
                                          style: "ok",
                                    }])
                        })
            }
      }
```

This is my render:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                  <Spinner
                        visible={spinnerState}
                        textContent={'Loading...'}
                        textStyle={{ color: 'rgb(200, 200, 200)' }} />
                  <View style={styles.containerSvg}>
                        <LinearBackground />
                  </View>
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
                        <View style={styles.containerAlign}>
                              // OTHER INPUTS
                              <ButtonAction onPress={handleAuthenticationAttempt} text={'LOGIN'} backgroundColor='rgba(20, 120, 160, 0.6)' />
                        </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
```

In theory this should work but it doesn't.
I have changed the spinner location multiple times but it never seems to show up. Any ideas on what's going on?

EDIT: Even when using setTimeout, the spinner never actually shows up.

Comment: Maybe its too fast try to set a timeout just to be sure that it actually can render it.

Comment: Nope doesn't render it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, had to use conditional rendering, which is quite strange considering other snack examples using what I had above worked.

```
{loadingStatus && <Spinner
                        visible={true}
                        textContent={'Loading...'}
                        textStyle={{
                              color: '#FFF'
                        }} />
                  }
```